# Creating Multiple Named Ranges using paramaters found in two excel column

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have any strong background in coding using sql so I always depend on stackoverflow and google for answers.

So I wanted to create multiple named ranges with the names dependent on values in Column A and with the "refer to" (Range) dependent on Column B.

I have managed to crunch some codes and they can create the named range for me but I can't seem to find a way to make vba do it row by row.

Here are my columns:
[image: Columns]

And here is my vba code:

```
Sub createNamedRange()

    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myRangeName As String

    Set myWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    myRangeName = myWorksheet.Range("A1").Value


    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=myWorksheet.Range("B1").Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is loop thrue all your rows, right?

I adjustet your code with a [For Loop](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html). It loops thrue your rows 1 to 4. If you want to loop thru more rows just adjust the loop settings. Hope it works for you.

```
Sub createNamedRange()

    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myRangeName As String
    Dim row         As Long

    Set myWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        For row = 1 To 4
            myRangeName = myWorksheet.Cells(row, 1).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=myWorksheet.cells(row,2).Text
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Works pretty well! @J.schmidt